# Acumatica 6.1 - Add dropdown option on Approval Map

Tags: acumatica

I need to customize the Assignments and Approval Maps to be able to create a rule based on the Subaccount on the Request Line.

The current dropdown options are Request, Ship Address, Ship Contact, Remit Address, Remit Contact, Approval, Employee, and Department. These correspond with the views in the RQRequestEntry business logic, eg. PXViewName(Messages.RQRequest). The data I need is the ExpenseSubID from the RQRequestLine DAC and part of the Lines view in the RQRequestEntry business logic.

Do I just need to add a view for Lines called RequestLines to add it to the dropdown? How do I do that?

I'm on Acumatica 6.10.0956.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was override the Lines view in the RQRequestEntry graph and add the PXViewName attribute for that view.

I followed this article:

https://help.acumatica.com/(W(12))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=5312e75a-6f0a-4b2c-a28c-38da20782087